# Reference three or more appendices in LaTeX article class

Tags: appendices, cleveref, article

I am writing a document using `article` class. I need to refer to multiple appendices. I am using `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages. When I refer to two sections in appendices, it writes Appendices A and B. When I refer to three sections in appendices, it writes Appendices A to C (see the screenshot below). I need it to write Appendices A, B and C. How can I do this? I attach the MWE.[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink, noabbrev]{cleveref}
\title{Something}
\author{Somebody}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
This paper studies economic dynamics. \Cref{app:derivation-focs,app:steady-state-conds}

This paper studies economic dynamics. \Cref{app:derivation-focs,app:steady-state-conds,app:sys-loglin-eq}
\newpage
\appendix
\section{Derivation of FOCs}\label{app:derivation-focs}
\section{Steady State Conditions}\label{app:steady-state-conds}
\section{System of Loglinear Equations}\label{app:sys-loglin-eq}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double commas in the list, which prevents the compression:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink, noabbrev]{cleveref}
\title{Something}
\author{Somebody}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
This paper studies economic dynamics. \Cref{app:derivation-focs,app:steady-state-conds}

This paper studies economic dynamics. \Cref{app:derivation-focs,,app:steady-state-conds,,app:sys-loglin-eq}
\newpage
\appendix
\section{Derivation of FOCs}\label{app:derivation-focs}
\section{Steady State Conditions}\label{app:steady-state-conds}
\section{System of Loglinear Equations}\label{app:sys-loglin-eq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note: The double comma only suppresses the compression at this place. So if you don't want to compress more than three, you have to use `,,` at every place, where want to prevent the compression — concrete: it „ensures that the preceding reference will appear explicitly in the final”. See the manual for more information.

Answer (score 3):

If you never want to compress references by `cleveref`, switch from the default option `sort&compress` to `sort` only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink, noabbrev, sort]{cleveref}
\title{Something}
\author{Somebody}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
This paper studies economic dynamics. \Cref{app:derivation-focs,app:steady-state-conds}

This paper studies economic dynamics. \Cref{app:derivation-focs,app:steady-state-conds,app:sys-loglin-eq}
\newpage
\appendix
\section{Derivation of FOCs}\label{app:derivation-focs}
\section{Steady State Conditions}\label{app:steady-state-conds}
\section{System of Loglinear Equations}\label{app:sys-loglin-eq}
\end{document}
```

[image: This paper studies economic dynamics. Appendices A and B. This paper studies economic dynamics. Appendices A, B and C]

See section “5 Sorting and Compressing” in [the `cleveref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) for more information.